# asp.net javascript mvc - how can I get javascript from inner page to clear element from outer page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I want javascript click event that's called from an "inner" mvc form to clear the element of the "outer"/"parent" form but clicking clear produces no results (see wireframe).
Javascript works on the outer form but not when called from scripts file reference in the inner form although I know that the script is wired up correctly b/c other behavior from the script is occurring.:

```
$("#clearField").on('click', function ()
{
    document.getElementById("playerCardNumber").value = "";
});
```

Environment: asp.net mvc 
[image]

Code for the outer/parent cshtml page:

```
@model adminLte.Models.playerCardData

<section class="content">

            <div class="inputPlayerInfo">
                @using (Ajax.BeginForm("WriteToGroup", "IT", new AjaxOptions  //action, view
                {
                    HttpMethod = "GET",
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                    UpdateTargetId = "innerPlayerInfoForm", //css tag (see below)
                    OnComplete = "ReturnData",
                    OnBegin = "ClearResults",
                    LoadingElementId = "divloading"
                }))
                {
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        <div class="divTable playerGroupTbl">
                            <div class="divTableBody">
                                <div class="divTableRow">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.playerCardNumber , htmlAttributes: new { @class = "divTableCell" })
                                    <div class="divTableCell">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.playerCardNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id= "playerCardNumber", @type ="password", @class = "form-control" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.playerCardNumber , "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <input type="submit" name="Command" value="Lookup Player" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" />
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="clearField" >Clear Previous Swipe</button>
                }
           </div>
           <br />

            @*form is inserted here*@
            <div id="divloading" style="display:none">
                <img src="~/images/giphy.gif" /> </div>
            <div id="innerPlayerInfoForm"></div>

</section>

@section scripts{
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function ReturnData()
        {
                $('#innerPlayerInfoForm').show();
            }
            function ClearResults()
            {
                $('#innerPlayerInfoForm').empty();
            }
            $('#playerEvent').selectpicker({
                size: 4
            });
            $("#clearField").on('click', function () {
                document.getElementById("playerCardNumber").value = "";
            });
        </script>
}
```

Code for the partial view:

```
@model adminLte.Models.eventModelParent

<div class="inputPlayerInfo">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("sproc_PlayerGroupInsert", "IT", new AjaxOptions  //action, view
    {
        HttpMethod = "GET",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "innerPlayerInfoForm", //css tag (see below)
        OnComplete = "ReturnData",
        OnBegin = "ClearResults"
    }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true;

        <div class="divTable playerGroupTbl">
            <div class="divTableBody">
                <div class="divTableRow">
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    <div class="divTableCell">
                        Event:
                    </div>
                        <div class="divTableCell">

                            @foreach (var _event in Model.vips)
                            {

                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.events.SelectedEvent, _event.eventId,
                                                        _event.eventchecked == 1 ? new { @checked = "checked" } : null
                               )  @:&nbsp  @_event.eventName
                                <br />
                            }

                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.events.SelectedEvent , "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="divTableRow" >
                    <div class="divTableCell"> Player ID: </div>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.playerData)
                    {
                        <div class="divTableCell">
                        <input style="border:none;background:transparent;"  id="PlayerID" name="PlayerID" value=@item.PlayerID readonly>
                         </div>
                    }
                </div>
                <div class="divTableRow someDivXYZ">
                    <div class="divTableCell"> Player First Name: </div>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.playerData)
                        {
                            <div class="divTableCell">
                            <input style="border:none;background:transparent;"  id="playerFirstName" name="playerFirstName" value=@item.playerFirstName readonly>
                            </div>
                    }
                </div>
                <div class="divTableRow someDivXYZ">
                    <div class="divTableCell"> Player Last Name: </div>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.playerData)
                    {
                        <div class="divTableCell">
                            <input style="border:none;background:transparent;"  id="playerLastName" name="playerLastName" value=@item.playerLastName readonly>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                        <input type="submit" id="updatePlayerGroup" value="Write This Player to Group" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" />
                        <button onclick="ClearResults()" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="clearField">Clear Selected Data</button>
                }
            </div>

            <div id="PlayerGroupInsertStatus"></div>
            @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/renderJS.js")
```

External js file:

```
$('#playerEvent').selectpicker({
    size: 4
});


$('#formEvent_playerEvent').selectpicker({
    size: 4
});

function ReturnData() {
    $('#PlayerGroupInsertStatus').show();
}

function beforeSend() {

    var PlayerID = document.getElementById("PlayerID").value;

}

$("#clearField").on('click', function ()
{
    document.getElementById("playerCardNumber") = "";
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated - thanks in advance!

Comment: By inner mvc form, you mean you are using partial views inside the main view?

Comment: What kind of element is the playercardswipe?  Show the html of the outer form element that you are trying to access with document.getElementById("playerCardNumber").  If you open Debug Console and paste that document.getElementById("playerCardNumber") into it what is the result?

Comment: Jerdine Sabio - Yes inner mvc form is a partial view - I updated the question with the code for clarification.

Comment: TheMikeInNYC - pasting document.getElementById("playerCardNumber") into the console yeilds the ID. Is this because there are 2 click events on the Clear Selected Data button?